# Why is my question at the very bottom of the question list?

Tags: support

A couple of days ago, I asked a question on SO ([1355657](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355657)).  When I went to look for it on the recent questions list, I couldn't find it.  I thought it might just show up later, so I just left it alone.

A day later, the question still didn't have any answers, so I revised it a bit to bump it back up.  I still couldn't find it on the recent questions list, but again, I left it alone.

Still unsatisfied with the answer (singular) that I had gotten, I decided to offer a bounty on the question to get it some visibility and maybe get some better answers.  I expected that when I did this, it would show up near the top of the "featured" questions list.  However, not only was it not near the top, it was *the very last question* in the three-page list, behind questions that were asked almost a year ago.

What's going on?  I'd really like to get some good answers to my SO question, but I don't know if I'll be able to if the question is dead last in the list.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question will never get bumped up the recent questions list. Edits, answers, and other general activity will cause your question to get bumped up the **Active** list, not the Recent/Newest one.

Also, the Hot Questions list will potentially come into play as well. That listing takes into account overall activity within shorter timeframes.

The featured questions list contains bounty items (ranked in terms of the oldest at the top...meaning the closest ones to expire).